# How to get a date variable from an object with a date in Java

Tags: java, date

I have an Object with the following text:

```
System.out.println("My date: " + valor);
```

and it prints

> My date: Thu Jan 01 13:00:00 CST 2015

I want to convert this text to a Date variable, this is my code:

```
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy",new Locale("es","MX"));
    try {
        Date dateToString = dateFormat.parse(valor.toString());

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        new Date();
    }
```

I always get current date, I've tried several combinations for SimpleDateFormat but none works, what's the proper way to convert my Object to a Date variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format doesn't include time zone (`z`) and you shouldn't swallow an `Exception` without logging it (which is how I found the error). Something like,

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
    Date dateToString = dateFormat.parse("Thu Jan 01 13:00:00 CST 2015");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dateToString));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
Thu Jan 01 13:00:00 CST 2015
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your date format isn't accounting for the timezone. Maybe try

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

[See Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)